# Can a schedule be a separate attachment in an email?

Tags: contract-law, england-and-wales

I have a contract which refers to schedule 1 which is another document. However in order to be able to add the document referred to in schedule 1 to the same document as my contract, I would need to convert the schedule 1 document to be the same filetype as my contract which I can't do.

So presuming that I sent the contract to the client in an email, could I then attach schedule 1 as a separate attachment to the contract in the email or does the schedule have to be in the same document as the contract?

Answer (score 2):

That the schedules are sent in different emails is almost entirely irrelevant provided the schedule is adequately named and referred to.

If Its still a concern you could mention the email is 1 of 2 and 2 of 2.  Also, from a technical POV there should be no difficulty attaching 2 files to a single email.